# How to add advanced options for CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, editor

When I go to /civicrm/admin/ckeditor at the end of the page I see "Adavanced options" which simply links me to the Api documenation of CKEditor - but how can I define these advanced option in CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

Right below that link is a set of dropdowns to select the advanced options.

[image]

Comment: hmmm... I don't see these options. I have an error in my browser console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () -> /libraries/civicrm/core/ext/ckeditor4/js/ck-options.json"`. I installed CiviCRM on Drupal 9 with composer using civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin to move javascipt into a web accessible folder which usually works well. May the problem be related to that configuration?

Comment: I see this file in remaining in vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/ext/ckeditor4/js/ck-options.json but it needs to be place in httpdocs/libraries... - why is this file not moved during composer install???

Comment: See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin/-/blob/master/default-config.json. The idea is it doesn't copy _everything_ because that would be insecure, but json does seem safe here. You could put in a PR against that extension to update the list. See also you can do a local customization in your drupal root composer.json: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin/-/tree/master#options

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Demerit.

The solution for now is to add the file to the composer.json:

```
"civicrm-asset": {
    "path": "httpdocs/libraries/civicrm",
    "url": "/libraries/civicrm",
    "assets:core": {
        "include": ["js/**", "css/**", "ang/**", "templates/**.png", "templates/**.jpg", "ext/ckeditor4/js/ck-options.json"],
        "exclude-dir": [".git", "/CRM"]
    }
```

After that run `composer civicrm:publish` and the options appear under /civicrm/admin/ckeditor.

I created an issue for the plugin: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin/-/issues/20